VsCode venv python.exe fails to run on subsequent debugs
I'm attempting to debug a Python based azure funciton using VsCode.  My launch.json file is posted below.

The first time i debugged the function, it worked without issue.  On subsequent debugs however, I get an error that python.exe failed to run:

It seems like the issue is with the python.exe file itself.  In order to troubleshoot, I deleted the python.exe file in the .venv/Scripts directory, and replaced it with a copy of my base python.exe file.
After I replaced the file, debugging worked on the initial attempt, however again on subsequent debugs I'm getting the same 'python.exe' failed to run error.
Every single time I replace the python.exe file, debug will work on the first attempt, and fail on all subsequent runs.

Whether or not to try to add "python": "path/to/python" (Absolute path to the Python interpreter executable; overrides workspace configuration if set.) configuration in launch.json.

unfortunately this didnt resolve the issue

Add this to your configuration in launch.json:
"envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/requirements.txt"
Make sure requirements.txt is not empty.
packageX==versionX
packageY==versionY
....

Edit
...and add this:
"postDebugTask": "func: host stop"

this unfortunately didn't solve the issue
